# Bash Variables within text block

Tags: bash

I am trying to get variables into a block of text which will later be echoed to a file.

Problem is the $VAR is not getting converted into the variable's value ??

```
VAR="SOME Value"

read -d '' WPA <<"BLOCK"
Description='WIFI'
Interface=wlan0
Connection=wireless
IP=dhcp
Security=wpa
Key=$VAR
BLOCK

echo "$WPA"
```

Also, is it possible to append further text to the WPA Block ?

Answer (score 2):

When you quote the delimeter of a heredoc, variables are not interpolated.  Just drop the quotes:

```
read -d '' WPA <<BLOCK
Description='WIFI'
Interface=wlan0
Connection=wireless
IP=dhcp
Security=wpa
Key=$VAR
BLOCK
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just say

```
WPA="Description='WIFI'
Interface=wlan0
Connection=wireless
IP=dhcp
Security=wpa
Key=$VAR
"
```

?

There's not really a need to use read in your case.

If you want to echo append text to $WPA, do it like this:

```
WPA="$WPA
first appended line
second appended line
"
```

but be aware that you insert an extra newline this way - $WPA had a newline at the end and there's another one at the beginning of the new text. To avoid this, use

```
WPA="${WPA}first appended line
second appended line
"
```

The {} quotation delimits the variable name. Using

```
WPA="$WPAfirst appended line
```

would look for a variable named WPAfirst.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to append further text to the WPA Block ?

`$WPA` is just a normal shell variable (that happens to contain a multi-line string), so you can append to it with `+=`; e.g.:

```
WPA+=$'\nanother line\nand another'
```

If you wanted to append the content of another *heredoc*, assign it to a separate variable and append that to `WPA` (but, as @GuntramBlohm points out, you can just as easily assign/append a multi-line string directly).